# Output the sorted array to main element

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and working with DOM, so please bear with me.

I have an array called num that I want to sort and display. The sort is a selection sort that returns the number of moves it took.

I can display the unsorted array but can't figure out how to call my sort function and then display the sorted array to the screen. My code is below:

```js
function fn(a, b) {
  if (a < b)
    return true;
}

function selection(list, fun) {
  var min, temp, count,
    len = list.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (fun(list[j], list[min])) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[min];
    listlist
    list[min] = temp;
    count += 3;
  }
  return count;
}

var num = [10, 1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4];

var demoP = document.getElementById("content");

{
  var html = "";
  html += "Original:" + num + "<br>";
  selection(num, fn);
  html += "Sorted:" + num + "<br>";
}

demoP.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: It was a challenge aspect to the sort method that was required for what I am doing.

Comment: It is a requirement for what I am doing, I realize it isn't the smartest way of doing this. But it is what is needed.

Comment: There's no variable `arr`, so it gets an error. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Is `arr[min]` supposed to be `list[min]`?

Comment: I forgot to change that one, it should be list. When I change it in my code, I am still not able to get an output

Comment: What is the line `listlist` supposed to do?

Comment: That looks like another typo. Get rid of it and the code works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really not sure how I missed that!!!!

Comment: How can you miss it when it displays an error in the console?

Comment: It didn't display it an error on my end. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is undefined, you should use `list` instead. Returning `count` returns the number of operations (after it's been initialized), return `list` instead. And as `list` is local to the function, you need to set `num` to the return value of the function call.

```html
<span id='content'/>
<script>
function fn(a, b) {
  if (a < b)
    return true;
}

function selection(list, fun) {
  var min, temp, count=0,
    len = list.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (fun(list[j], list[min])) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[min];

    list[min] = temp;
    count += 3;
  }
  return list;
}

var num = [10, 1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4];

var demoP = document.getElementById("content"); 


  var html = "";
  html += "Original:" + num + "<br>";
  num=  selection(num, fn);
  html += "Sorted:" + num + "<br>";


demoP.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```